# How to acces parent table from a field code during mail merge in a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, openxml-sdk, mailmerge

```
I have a docx word document that contains table and table cell with mergefield inside.
```

[image]

I want to change the background of the table cell to orange value (#EA6E24) but I don't find the field and the way to do it.

So here is my code that process the mail merge of the field and try to add a shading to the table cell.

```
 fldCode = parent.Descendants<FieldCode>().FirstOrDefault();

 if (fldCode != null && fldCode.InnerText.Contains("MERGEFIELD") &&
 {
    var ancestors = fldCode.Ancestors<TableCell>();

    // trouver et colorier le parent
    fieldName = "";

    var shading = new Shading()
    {
        Color = "auto",
        Fill = "#EA6E24",
        Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear
    };

    foreach (var ancestor in ancestors)
    {
        ancestor.Append(shading);
    }                 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to access and overwrite the shading property.

```
 foreach (var ancestor in ancestors)
   {
         var tableCellProperties = ancestor.TableCellProperties;
         tableCellProperties.Shading = shading;                            
   }
```